# Python: Web scraping multiple years

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning about data analytics. In an effort to learn how to scrape websites, I followed the following the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nt7WJa2iu0s. It is extremely helpful. But now I want to pull multiple years. I thought changing the code from `years = list(range(2022, 2020, -1))` to `years = list(range(2022, 2020, 2018, -1))` would pull an extra year but I am getting the following error message:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 years = list(range(2022, 2020, 2018, -1))
>
> TypeError: range expected at most 3 arguments, got 4
> Here is my code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd 


standings_url = "fbref.com/en/comps/9/2021-2022/2021-2022-Premier-League-Stats" 

data = requests.get(standings_url) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text) 

standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0] 

links = standings_table.find_all('a') 
links = [l.get("href") for l in links] 
links = [l for l in links if '/squads/' in l] 

team_urls = [f"fbref.com{l}" for l in links] 
team_url = team_urls[0] 

data = requests.get(team_url) 

matches = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Scores & Fixtures")
soup=BeautifulSoup(data.text) 

links=soup.find_all('a') 
links = [l.get("href") for l in links] 
links=[l for l in links if l and 'all_comps/shooting/' in l] 

data = requests.get(f"fbref.com{links[0]}") 

shooting=pd.read_html(data.text, match="Shooting")[0] 
shooting.columns = shooting.columns.droplevel() 

team_data = matches[0].merge(shooting[["Date", "Sh", "SoT", "Dist", "FK", "PK", "PKatt"]], on="Date") 

years = list(range(2022, 2020, 2018, -1))
```

What did I do incorrectly? How do I pull multiple years? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ashley, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Would you be able to add all of the code you have to your question? Thanks!

Comment: import requests
standings_url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2021-2022/2021-2022-Premier-League-Stats"
data = requests.get(standings_url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]
links = standings_table.find_all('a')
links = [l.get("href") for l in links]
links = [l for l in links if '/squads/' in l]
team_urls = [f"https://fbref.com{l}" for l in links]
team_url = team_urls[0]
data = requests.get(team_url)
import pandas as pd

matches = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Scores & Fixtures")

Comment: Ashley do you have anything else?

Comment: soup=BeautifulSoup(data.text)
links=soup.find_all('a')
links = [l.get("href") for l in links]
links=[l for l in links if l and 'all_comps/shooting/' in l]
data = requests.get(f"https://fbref.com{links[0]}")
shooting=pd.read_html(data.text, match="Shooting")[0]
shooting.columns = shooting.columns.droplevel()
team_data = matches[0].merge(shooting[["Date", "Sh", "SoT", "Dist", "FK", "PK", "PKatt"]], on="Date")
years = list(range(2022, 2020, 2018, -1))

Comment: Then I get the error

Comment: Oh that looks funny. I hope you can understand all that. If not, let me know how I can share it all with you.

Comment: Ashley I added it to your question. Please check my answer and lmk how it goes!

Comment: You are a lifesaver. It works! I knew it would be something simple but I was going crazy trying to figure it out! hahaha...thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the years from 2022 to 2018, then you can use:

```
years = list(range(2022, 2018, -1))

# to see what it creates, you can use:
[i for i in range(2022, 2018, -1)]
# or 
print(years) # [2022, 2021, 2020, 2019]
```

The way that `range` works is:

> `range(start, stop, step=1)`

So you want to set the first parameter to the starting year, the second to the last year, and the third to be the change from one value to the next. (e.g. -1 means you go backwards, from (for example) 2020 to 2019). If you don't set the last parameter, it will default to 1.

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. Woo hooooo!

Comment: Ahhh, you got me with that link. :^)

Comment: @Ashley if I solved the question, you can mark it as solved :-)